# Nextjs getInitialProps query.id is undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get the id from the route as http//localhost:3000/portfolios/helloworld so id is helloworld. But i get an error that says TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'query' as it is undefined.

```
const PortfolioDetail = ({ query }) => {
  const { id } = query;
  return <h1>I am Details Page with ID: {id}</h1>;
};

PortfolioDetail.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
  return { query };
};

export default PortfolioDetail;
```

I tried the same thing with class component but the error was same.

```
// class PortfolioDetail extends React.Component {
//   static getInitialProps({ query }) {
//     return { query };
//   }

//   render() {
//     const id = this.props.query.id;
//     return <h1>I am Detail Page with id : {id} </h1>;
//   }
// }

// export default PortfolioDetail;
```

this is my project structure you can see below image

[image: this is my project structure]

It only works and i can get my id using useRouter i showed below.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';

const PortfolioDetail = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const id = router.query.id 
  return <h1>I am Details Page with ID: {id}</h1>;
};

PortfolioDetail.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
  return { query };
};

export default PortfolioDetail;
```

I am stuck at this point and i really wanna know why it won't work.

Comment: Maybe you are doing something weird in your custom `_app.js`? You need to pass `pageProps` to the `Component` there, are you doing it?

Comment: `
import '../styles/index.scss';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const MyApp = ({ Component, ...pageProps }) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};
export default MyApp;
`
this is my _app.js

Comment: Well, that's strange then. I made quick example with your code, it works perfectly fine https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68240185-e86d9?file=/pages/portfolios/%5Bid%5D.js

Comment: yeah. You proved that i must have some problem with my local environment with nextjs. Otherwise there is no reason for that id to come undefined no matther what i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it, you have an error in your `_app`:

```
import '../styles/index.scss';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

// Don't need to spread pageProps here
const MyApp = ({ Component, ...pageProps }) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};

export default MyApp;
```

It should be:

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You filled a big gap inside of me :) Why am i spreading pageProps on MyApp parameters... I will never forget that mistake from now on. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use it like the code shown below

```
  export default function FirstPost({ id }) {
    console.log("-->", id);
    return (
      <>
        {id}sdlfdfdlkj
      </>
    );
  }

  FirstPost.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
    return { id: query?.id };
  };
```

Comment: it came undefined again. It must be some reason underneath.